# Runtime Error: failed to connect to camera service in android

Tags: android, android-camera

I wanted to make use of the zxing library to detect qrcodes in my app. But for the apps viewing purpose, i had to change the custom display orientation to portrait. Hence i had to integrate the whole zxing library into my app and addded camera.setDisplayOrientation(90) to the openDriver() method.
After doing this, the program works, but I get "Runtime exceptions : Fail to connect to camera service" randomly.

```
public void openDriver(SurfaceHolder holder) throws IOException {
  if (camera == null) {
      camera = Camera.open();
      camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

      if (camera == null) {
          throw new IOException();
      }
  }
  camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
  if (!initialized) {
  initialized = true;
  configManager.initFromCameraParameters(camera);
}
configManager.setDesiredCameraParameters(camera);

SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
reverseImage = prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.KEY_REVERSE_IMAGE, false);
if (prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.KEY_FRONT_LIGHT, false)) {
  FlashlightManager.enableFlashlight();
 }
}

public void closeDriver() {
    if (camera != null) {
        FlashlightManager.disableFlashlight();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        framingRect = null;
        framingRectInPreview = null;
    }
}

/**
 * Asks the camera hardware to begin drawing preview frames to the screen.
 */
public void startPreview() {
    if (camera != null && !previewing) {
        camera.startPreview();
        previewing = true;
    }
}

/**
 * Tells the camera to stop drawing preview frames.
 */
public void stopPreview() {
    if (camera != null && previewing) {
        if (!useOneShotPreviewCallback) {
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        }
        camera.stopPreview();
        previewCallback.setHandler(null, 0);
        autoFocusCallback.setHandler(null, 0);
        previewing = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that the orientation change is causing that. I have found you will get that error whenever an activity stops but fails to call Camera.release in their onPause. The result is that the next time you try to do Camera.open you get that runtime error since the driver still considers it open regardless of the app/activity that opened it being gone.

You can easily get this to happen while debugging/testing stuff when something throws an exception and brings the activity down. You need to be very diligent about catching all exceptions and being sure to release the camera before finishing the activity.

BTW, are you finding you need to power cycle the device in order to be able to open the camera again?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, for it to work again, i need to restart the device. Well i would agree with you if the problem happened always I exit the app and run again. But this happens very randomly. I am making sure to release the camera in the onPause() as well as onDestroy().

Comment: Are you certain the app isnt crashing sometimes and then not getting through to onPause or onDestroy? onDestory is no guaranteed to be called and I suspect onPause will also be skipped in the event of an uncaught exception in the activity. Could you maybe do some logging and use logcat to confirm your app ended normally before the runtime exception?

Comment: Yes, i have been doing that. The main problem is that i am not able to recreate the situation as this happens randomly. Is it possible that in some cases the camera is taking longer time to release and hence the resources are not released entirely for the next time the program runs?

Comment: No, I've never heard of release taking too long...it's a blocking call anyway so once you return from it it has been done.  I really still believe you have something that is causing your app to quit and your onPause (assuming you call Camera.release from there) is not getting called. If you have try/catch most everywhere and it's still random, then that would sound like your app is getting killed for out of memory, which would explain not catching anything & the seeming randomness, since you can never catch the out of memory case. Examine logcat output carefully to see if getting force closed

Comment: I figured out when I get the error. It happens when I press the power off button to make the screen off(not powering the device off). After sometime when i switch on the screen , i get this runtime exception(If i immdiately switch on the screen, i dont get this error). I still dont understand why this error happens, because when the screen turns off, the app enters the onPause() where i am releasing the camera!